# Django ORM - MySQL query count optimization for related models

Tags: mysql, django, orm, django-rest-framework

I have two related models, that looks like below:

```
class Enterprise(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subsystem_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    modif_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subsystem_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    modif_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    enterprise = models.ForeignKey('Enterprise'
    on_delete = CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

In my view, need to get all active Enterprises and list them. I'm doing it this way:

```
enterprise_list = Enterprise.objects.annotate(project_count=Count('project')).filter(
    Q(active=True) | Q(subsystem_id=-1), project_count__gt=0
)

serializer = EnterpriseSerializer(enterprise_list, many=True)
```

Then, my serializer is displaying project list with some additional query:

```
class EnterpriseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
    project_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_project_list(self, enterprise):
        project_list = Project.objects.filter(Q(active=True) | Q(subsystem_id=-1),
                                              enterprise=enterprise)
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(project_list, many=True)
        return serializer.data

    class Meta:
        model = Enterprise
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'project_list')
```

This code is working fine, but it has very serious issue - performance. The first query for Enterprise returns list of ~1500 object. Then, for every object, serializer executes single query to fetch additional data for project which results to ~1500 queries.

I've tried `prefetch_related` and `select_related` but either I'm doing something wrong or it doesn't work in my case.

In the other hand I can get list of project first. This could eliminate my count annotation. But I should group them by enterprise, but as far as I know Django ORM for MySQL doesn't support such operations. I don't think parse the data in python and pass it to serializer as a dict is a good idea.

Can you give me some tips how to limit queries in my case? Maybe `prefetch/select_related` will be helpful in my case, but how to use them properly here? I'm using MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prefetch_related` the following way:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

enterprise_list = Enterprise.objects.annotate(project_count=Count('project')).filter(
    Q(active=True) | Q(subsystem_id=-1), 
    project_count__gt=0).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('project_set', 
            queryset=Project.objects.filter(Q(active=True) | Q(subsystem_id=-1)), 
            to_attr='projects'
        )
    )

serializer = EnterpriseSerializer(enterprise_list, many=True)
```

In serializer.py

```
class EnterpriseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def get_project_list(self, enterprise):
        project_list = enterprise.projects
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(project_list, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

Comment: Oh, so I've used prefetch_related completely wrong. Thanks for clarifying.